# SQL select row in one table, for whose key row in another table has given values

Tags: mysql, sql, select

It is difficult to explain what I want in the title, some I'll try to do it with an example here. I have 2 tables:

```
[Table1]
set_id | data
-------+-----
   1   | 123
   2   | 456
   3   | 789
   4   | 987

[Table2]
set_id | single_id
-------+----------
   1   |    10
   2   |    10
   2   |    13
   3   |    10
   3   |    13
   3   |    14
   4   |    10
   4   |    15
```

I need to select row in `Table1` with such `set_id` that in `Table2` rows with same `set_id` have `single_id`s only those given in query. For example:

For query `(10, 13)` resulting row should be `2 | 456`.

For query `(10)` resulting row should be `1 | 123`.

For query `(10, 13, 14)` resulting row should be `3 | 789`.

How this can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of a `set-within-sets` subquery.  I think the most general approach is to use aggregation with a `having` clause:

```
select t1.set_id, t1.data
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.set_id = t2.set_id
group by t1.set_id
having sum(t2.single_id = 10) > 0 and
       sum(t2.single_id = 13) > 0 and
       sum(t2.single_id not in (10, 13)) = 0;
```

Each condition in the `having` clause tests one condition.  The first is that a row with `10` is present; the second that a row with `13` is present.  And the last that no other values are present.

EDIT:

In MySQL, there is actually another approach which might seem more intuitive:

```
select t1.set_id, t1.data
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.set_id = t2.set_id
group by t1.set_id
having group_concat(distinct t2.single_id order by t2.single_id) = '10,13';
```

That is, concatenate the distinct values together, in order, and compare them to a constant string.

Comment: +1) Your answers are really great.here is your answer http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/727453/2